# On prem Active directory synced to Azure AD to allow on prem credentials to login to the portal

Tags: azure-active-directory

We have synced our on prem active directory to our Azure instance active directory using Azure AD connect (Express install).  We can see the users in Azure from our on prem AD. The sync shows as successful.

Now we would like to use the domain name that we have synced to azure for user authentication in to the azure portal. The documentation that we have read says this is possible, but we can get it to work.

When we try to use an existing AD user we get the message that “We don’t recognize this users ID or password”  but if we create a new user in Azure and assign it to our  synced AD we can use it to login to the azure portal.

We have searched for a detailed document on prem AD synced to Azure AD  to use for portal login and found some documents that we followed but did not help.

Can we use our on prem AD user name and password to allow users to login to the Azure portal?

Thanks for your help
John

Comment: Did you enable password synchronization when you set up Azure AD Connect?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use users in Azure AD with tag "Sourced from: Local Active Direcotry" to login to azure portal.

The custom domain should be verified.

Password Synchronization should be enabled.

Also, assign coadmin right for at least one subscription to login to Management Portal.